# ORA-1000 Cursor count exceeded. Doesn't replicate on different servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, cursor

I have two different IIS servers that are running IIS 7.0 and running the same build of code for my ASP.NET web application with an Oracle back-end.  They are both using the same Oracle database but when I run the application on one server, it causes a Cursor Count Exceeded error whereas on the other server the code runs perfectly fine and never encounters the error.  The one that is "broken" just so happens to be the production server vs. the development server.

What would be the cause of this?  And if there is a way to kill Oracle Sessions in ASP.NET, how do you do it besides waiting for them to timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it was the ORA-01000 error, the solution is simple, increase the value of open_cursors in the database configuration.

Assuming a release >= 10g and using spfile:

```
alter system set open_cursors = 512;
```

The change should be in effect immediately.
The default value (50?) is a bit low for many situation.